# Cannot ping my new AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ping

Everyone,

I've created my first one AWS instance a day ago. After few tests, it seems that my AWS EC2 instance is not reachable from my network, but also from the others networks (see bellow, maybe not on yours?).

Indeed, when I try a simple `ping -t myInstance.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com` it doesn't work.

According to some other posts, I disable my firewall, and I added some security rules over aws (all TCP/ICMP/RDP/SSH, on `::/0` and `0.0.0.0/0`). Added the Custom ICMP rule for Echo Requests.

Moreover, I haven't a proxy.

Finaly, a simple ping on google works.

If you want to test by yourself (maybe it works ?) : my instance is `ec2-18-220-216-155.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com` or `18.220.216.155` (IPV4)

**Do you have any ideas of what I can do to reach my AWS instance ?**

Thanks, Clément

Comment: It's not pingable for me. I think there needs to be a more well-defined question, though.

Comment: What else can I define ?

Comment: Missing info. Windows or Linux? Is it in VPC public or private subnet?  Can you remove all rules in SG and add a single rule to allow all traffic from everywhere? You said `a simple ping on google works`, what does it mean?

Comment: Why do you wish to ping? If you want to be able to connect via SSH or HTTP, then try that connection rather than using a Ping. Ping is not good from a security standpoint and should be disabled by default. Can you SSH into the instance?

Comment: Wanted to ping to know if my instance can be reashed. It was like a shitty idea but this same idea was supposed to work. 

I found the problem : I was supposed to change the settings on my computer to allow ping commands, and it's what I've done. But on tutorials, they didn't said I was supposed to change the settings to allow ping commands on the VM too !! 

Indeed, you need to allow ping commands on the security groups (said on the tutorial) but also on the VM itself ! (Parameters center, security, ...). Thanks for all m8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution :**

The tutorials on Stackoverflow or other forums are explaining that we need to :

1- Disable (open) your proxy if any

2- Add security rules on AWS : (you can add all protocols if you want to test).

3- On your computer (Windows) : go on Control Panel, Windows Firewall and right click on "Inbound rules". You should be able to activate "ICMP IPV4" protocols. If not, just add it ! :)

**What tutorials doesn't explain :**

4- You also need to add rules on you Windows Firewall Settings **ON THE AWS VM !!** (if it's a Windows one). Indeed, by default, it's refusing the ping protocols !!!!!!  (Just repeat the 3- on your Windows VM).

Hope it helped.

Clément